# TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings on subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, arguments, subprocess, parameter-passing, popen

I am trying to execute an external command inpython.

The command arguments , if executed in the shell are as follows:

```
osmconvert inputfile -b=bbox -o=outputfile
```

I am trying to call it with subprocess as fowlloows:

```
import subprocess as sb

inputfile = '/path/to/inputfile'    
outputfile = '/path/to/outputfile'
bbox = 13.400102,52.570951,13.61957,52.676858

test = sb.Popen(['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b=', bbox, '-o=',outputfile])
```

That gives me the error msg : `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Can anyone hint on how to make this work?

Kind regards!

Comment: Try str(inputfile) ? You could also do the same for the other. (output file)

Comment: What part of `arg 2 must contain only strings` is unclear?

Comment: tried inputfile = str('/path/to/inputfile' )
outputfile = str('/path/to/outputfile') , same error :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error you're getting is due to `bbox` being a tuple of floats, rather than a string. If you want the `-b` parameter to be passed like `-b= 13.400102,52.570951,13.61957,52.676858`, you'll probably want to put quotes around the `bbox` value.

You may have a further issue though. Note the space I put in the parameter string above. If you pass `bbox` and `outputfile` as separate parameters from the `'-b='` and `'-o='` strings, you'll get the equivalent of a space between their values and the equals sign in the command that is called. This may or may not work, depending on how `osmconvert` handles its command line argument parsing. If you need the `-b` and `-o` flags to be part of the same argument as the strings that follow them, I'd suggest using `+` to concatenate the strings together:

```
inputfile = '/path/to/inputfile'    
outputfile = '/path/to/outputfile'
bbox = '13.400102,52.570951,13.61957,52.676858' # add quotes here!

 # concatenate some of the args with +
test = sb.Popen(['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b='+bbox, '-o='+outputfile])
```

Comment: also, `['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b', bbox, '-o', outputfile]` might work (no `=`, separate arguments).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That might work, I'm not sure. Like I said, it depends on how `osmconvert` parses its parameters. All the example usages I see online use the equals sign and concatenated values, but the tool itself might be more forgiving than the examples show.

Comment: Ok the concatenation using the + made it work finally ! Thanks !! And  @J.F.Sebastian : In the case of osmconvert I cant leave away the =, I tried, didnt work.

Comment: @ray: did you drop `=` *and* put the values into separate arguments (no `+`)?

Comment: I used it like that `test = sb.Popen(['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b='+bbox, '-o='+outputfile])`

Comment: @ray: I've asked about your *"I tried, didnt work"*  comment: what error do you get if you run `sb.check_call(['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b', bbox, '-o', outputfile])` as is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `bbox` into the required string representation:

```
test = sb.Popen(['osmconvert', inputfile, '-b', '%d,%d,%d,%d' % tuple(bbox), '-o',outputfile])
```

Comment: I doubt `%d` is the right conversion to use for floating point values, since it will truncate them to integers. Probably `%f` would be more appropriate, though you might want to specify a precision.